# Codeigniter4 Templating performance

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, optimization, codeigniter-4

How to template the codeigniter4 project for best performance? There are two scenarios:

1. Pass view to controller and then echo it on the page

```
 $this->_page_data['bottom'] = $this->bottom();
```

and then in view render it by echoing

```
echo $bottom
```

2. Include the template using include_once

```
    <?php include_once(APPPATH  .'Views/bottom.php');?>
```

Which would be better for performance?

Comment: I really doubt there are any noticeable performance differences. Are you having any specific issues, or is it just a case of premature optimization? And why not use [View Layouts](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/view_layouts.html) instead?

Comment: Just premature optimization.
Just wanted to know the best way to template project.
As opensource like wp, opencart we pass view via controller rather than including the file so was just checking the best solution

Comment: The difference between the methods are so small so you really shouldn't bother. Prematurely optimizing such small details are pointless and just a time waster. If your system starts being slow, it won't be because of this. You should then profile/debug your application and find what task causes the slowness and try and optimize that instead.